# Как определяется приложение и определяемое слово?

Tags: приложение

Почему в сочетании  сестра Маша приложением является "сестра", а в сочетаниях река Москва, газета "Труд" приложением являются "Москва" и "Труд"? Почему такое разное отношение к именам собственным и нарицательным?

**Может быть, здесь заключена особая философия,** потому что грамматические формы совершенно тождественны и ведут себя одинаковым образом: Маша-сестра, Москва-река.   Как мне кажется, грамматика - это форма, которая наполняется определенным содержанием, и это **содержание не должно  влиять на форму и изменять форму.**

Так есть ли здесь особое толкование,  как-то мне ничего не встречалось на эту тему.

Спасибо за ваши ответы.

Answer (score 2):

> > Почему в сочетании сестра Маша приложением является "сестра"

При сочетании собственного имени лица и имени нарицательного в роли приложения выступает последнее. *Инженер Петрова составила проект реконструкции цеха* (сказуемое согласуется с подлежащим, а не с приложением)

(Розенталь Д. Э. и др. Словарь лингвистических терминов)

Сравните:
***Река* Днепр *широка* и *глубока***.

Может быть, поэтому?

Comment: Я уже думаю, что при сочетании нарицательного и собственного имен вообще некорректно говорить о приложении, которое является ОПРЕДЕЛЕНИЕМ. Вот у меня учебник "Практическая стилистика", и там написано: Врач Петрова окончила прием (врач - подлежащее, Петрова (имя лица) - приложение). Также: Цветок лилия очень вырос (цветок - подлежащее, лилия - приложение, то есть родовое и видовое наименование). Таким образом, мы имеем два названия для одного предмета, а не определение, отнесенное к предмету.

Comment: Вера, а кто автор этой книги? Спрашиваю, потому что не понимаю, на что здесь указывает приложение ''Петрова''.